# Failed to install Oracle client with an error "path is too long"

Tags: windows, path, oracle-10g, oracle-11g, oracle-12c

I'd like to know how to install Oracle Client on my Windows 10 pro PC/Dell Vostro 3860 properly cause of I got a problem to install the client software that "PATH is too long" error.

What I tried to installed it with administrator tools after I got an error message?

1. Deleted unnecessary program path in PATH variable such DELL and
   INTEL after I backed up them.
2. Amended program path in PATH variable to 8.3 format if
       it's over 8 character length.
3. Saved them and Reboot PC just in case.
4. Tried to install Oracle Client with Administrator privilege after I copied installer files and folders locally just in case.

No luck.

It's still same message appeared when to install it.

So, I'm stuck there that I can not proceed to install it due to the error.
This is brand new Windows 10 pro PC that has latest patches.

Oracle Client: Oracle 11g

Could you tell me how to install Oracle client properly and fix this issue?
Otherwise I have to reinstall Windows 10 pro that will be taking so long to setup in my environment due to no internet connection. Unfortunately.

Comment: In which directory are you installing ?

Comment: @harrymc, I tried to install it under c:\app\ after removed my windows profile name such administrator. It was c:\app\administrator\ before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long long time ago and in some far away Windows,
environmental variables were limited to 1023 characters.

Older installations still remember with longing those times and behave as if
they still have validity today.
Unfortunately the Oracle installation is one of these time-frozen ones.

Your problem is the PATH environmental variable for SYSTEM,
which is too long for Oracle.
You need to reduce it so that after Oracle adds its own, the entire length
will not exceed 1023.

The trimming of PATH could be made easier by using the free
[System Path Commander](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Other/Spc/index.html).

Of course, nothing stops you from adding everything back to PATH once
you have finished, and Oracle will keep on working quite happily.
System Path Commander can help in that by using the right-click menu
command "Copy Checked Dirs to Clipboard" for saving and the "Add..." command
for restoring.

As a safety measure, you could create first a system restore point,
just in case.

Comment: Thank you. I will try System Path Commander. Then get back to you.

Comment: Thank you. It's almost fixed. I have one more problem when to install Oracle client that was the installation path has to be setup with "/" anyhow. Then, It worked. I'm afraid I can not tell exactly now. I quite my job recently. Anyway, It worked.